# SwiftUI: Widgets and Core Data

Tags: core-data, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm trying to create a widget that makes use of Core Data, and in the widget extension, I can't import the project module:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents
import MyProjectModule
import CoreData
...
...
...
struct CrossFitLoggerWidgetEntryView : View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Exercise"), animation: .default)
    private var fetchedResults: FetchedResults
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(fetchedResults, id: \.self) { (loggedExercise: Exercise) in
            Text(loggedExercise.exerciseName)
        }
    }
}
```

The `Exercise` class is the core data automatically generated class, which I guess should be imported in the widget extension via my project so I can make use of it?

Is there any step I'm missing? The `xcdatamodel` file is already added to the widget extension target and I have already created an `AppGroup`.

Comment: Import the project module? If you added the model to the widget target you don’t need to import. You have to add all the files want to share to the target. Unless you are trying to use a framework you haven’t provided enough information on your setup to help you with more.

Comment: If I remote the import statement, then it complains that for example ‘Exercise’ can’t be found. Also Exercise is core data generated so I don’t know how to add it to the widget extension?

Comment: It gets added when you add the xcdatamodel to the target.

Comment: Indeed it does: I only had to close Xcode, clean the build folder, rebuild two times, reboot the laptop and sacrifice a lama for it to work, but it does now! Thanks a lot for the help!